# Using returned value in SQL Server Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Trying to get a result set by retrieving an ID from one table and using that value to retrieve the results in the same procedure.

This returns the correct userID but not the traveler information.

```
USE [GrandCelebration]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[update_system_emails_audit_read_date]    Script Date: 4/21/2015 10:44:52 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserID]
    @UniqueKey varchar(20)
AS


DECLARE @ReturnValue int

SELECT @ReturnValue=UserId FROM SystemEmailsAudit WHERE UniqueKey=@UniqueKey;
RETURN @ReturnValue
Go
DECLARE @ReturnValue int
Select * from LeadTravelers where CertificateID = @ReturnValue
```

Comment: Does `CertificateID ` and `UserId ` have FK relation between two table?

Comment: Use an output parameter. Return values are for returning error/status codes, not data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return the rows from `LeadTravelers` table by modifing the store procedure.

```
USE [GrandCelebration]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[update_system_emails_audit_read_date]    Script Date: 4/21/2015 10:44:52 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserID]
    @UniqueKey varchar(20)
AS
Begin

    DECLARE @ReturnValue int

    SELECT @ReturnValue=UserId FROM SystemEmailsAudit WHERE UniqueKey=@UniqueKey;

    Select * from LeadTravelers where CertificateID = @ReturnValue

    end 

Go
```

Comment: The variable `@ReturnValue` is not required. You can use `JOIN` to get the data from `LeadTravelers` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` instead of using variable,

```
USE [GrandCelebration]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[update_system_emails_audit_read_date]    Script Date: 4/21/2015 10:44:52 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserID]
    @UniqueKey varchar(20)
AS
Begin

        SELECT UserId 
        FROM SystemEmailsAudit 
        WHERE UniqueKey = @UniqueKey;

        SELECT LT.* FROM LeadTravelers LT
        JOIN SystemEmailsAudit SEA 
        ON LT.CertificateID = SEA.UserId
        WHERE SEA.UniqueKey = @UniqueKey;
end 
Go
```

Comment: I changed the SEA UniqueKey to SEA.UserID it returned all rows not the one that matches the selected userID above it.